# An equivalence relation on filters

Tags: equivalence-relations, filters

Let $F$ be a filter.
We say $ X \sim_{f} Y $ iff $X \leftrightarrow Y$ $\in$ $F$. 
I am able to prove reflexivity and associativity of the relation but not the transitivity. 
Need help with that. Use the definition of double implication with join and meet operations.

Comment: The question explicitly says how to proceed.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I cant seem to achieve the result using join and meet operations..

Comment: What result do you achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logic, we have $X\to Y\ =(\lnot X)\lor Y$, so the corresponding set operation is $X^\complement\cup Y\ \ \left( = (X\setminus Y)^\complement\ \right)$.

Thus, for sets $X\leftrightarrow Y$ would mean $(X^\complement\cup Y)\,\cap\,(Y^\complement \cup X)\ =\ (X^\complement\cap Y^\complement)\,\cup\,(X\cap Y)\ =$ 
$=\ (X\cup Y)^\complement\,\cup\,(X\cap Y)$.

For elements, we can say that $s\in X\leftrightarrow Y$ iff either $s$ is in both sets, or is in neither of them.

**Hint:** Prove that $(X\leftrightarrow Y)\ \cap\ (Y\leftrightarrow Z)\ \subseteq\ (X\leftrightarrow Z)$.

**Update:** In an abstract Boolean algebra, you can also prove this. Perhaps easier to prove first $(X\to Y)\land (Y\to Z)\,\le\, (X\to Z)\ $ (using the definition $A\to B:=\lnot A\lor B$), then we can combine to get
$$(X\leftrightarrow Y)\,\land\, (Y\leftrightarrow Z) = \big((X\to Y)\land (Y\to X)\big) \ \land\ \big((Y\to Z)\land (Z\to Y)\big) \ =\\
=\ (X\to Y)\land (Y\to Z)\ \land\ (Z\to Y)\land (Y\to X)\ \le\ 
(X\to Z)\,\land\,(Z\to X)\,.$$

Comment: Well it seem obvious in case of sets. Thanks to you. :)
But I don't see how to do the same for arbitrary join and meet operations.

Comment: What do you mean by '*arbitrary join and meet*' operations? I guessed, a 'filter' means a set of *subsets of some base set* which is upward closed and is also closed under binary intersections. Or, did you mean more generally, a filter in an arbitrary lattice / Boolean algebra or what?

Comment: Anyway, if you insist, you can prove it without using elements: just substitute any $A\leftrightarrow B\ $ by $\ (A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\ \cup\ (A\cap B)$.

Comment: Yep, I meant a filter in arbitrary Boolean Algebra.

Comment: Ok, I added an update, hope it helps.

Comment: We dont have to show the other way right(in case that holds) because this is sufficient for the rhs to be inside the filter ?